# Ionic 1 : Delay in alpha indexed list with large data

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting issue while redirecting to ion-list template with approx. 700 items. There comes a delay of around 4-5 seconds which is decreasing performance.Below is my code. Can someone please suggest me the solution?

```
<ion-modal-view class="bgImg">
<ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-light">
        <h1><img class="title-image titleImg" src="img/logoIB.png"/></h1>
            <div class="buttons button-clear">
              <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="refreshList()" style="margin-top:40px;"><i class="icon ion-refresh" style="font-size:30px;"></i></button>
            </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content scroll="true" >
        <div data-ng-repeat="(letter, authors) in sorted_users" class="alpha_list">
            <ion-item class="item item-divider" id="index_{{letter}}">
                {{letter}}
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="author in authors" ng-click="getSelectedUser(author.user_id,author.passcode,author.gesturecode,author.username)">
                {{author.last_name}} {{author.first_name}}
            </ion-item>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
    <ul class="alpha_sidebar">
        <li ng-click="gotoList('index_{{letter}}')" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet">
            {{letter}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</ion-view>
```